# Unable to see why different threads are not picking up the tasks

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I tried running the following code but was not able to identify why the same thread picked up the task instead of different threads.

```kotlin
fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {
    launch {
        delay(100L)
        println(Thread.currentThread().name + "Task 1")
    }

    launch {
        delay(100L)
        println(Thread.currentThread().name + "Task 2")
    }

    launch {
        delay(100L)
        println(Thread.currentThread().name + "Task 3")
    }

    println(Thread.currentThread().name + "Main thread is over")
}
```

Output:

```
mainMain thread is over
mainTask 1
mainTask 2
mainTask 3

Process finished with exit code 0
```

PS: I am still learning kotlin. Please forgive if this is a naive question.

Comment: One thing to know is that, since your coroutines just sleep most of the time, even a multithreaded dispatcher could choose to run them all on the same thread. They spend 99.99% of their time not executing on any thread, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your are using launch without parameters inside of some scope, runBlocking in this case

> When launch { ... } is used without parameters, it inherits the
> context (and thus dispatcher) from the CoroutineScope it is being
> launched from. In this case, it inherits the context of the main
> runBlocking coroutine which runs in the main thread.
> https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html

The default CoroutineDispatcher for runBlocking is a proprietary internal implementation. https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html

What you could do is use launch with parameters, i.e GlobalScope.launch{}. Or you could experiment with giving runBlocking different contexts, which will result in a different CoroutineDispatcher being used when launch is called without parameters.

Examples for different contexts can be found here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
fun main() {
    runBlocking<Unit>(Dispatchers.Default) {
    launch {
        delay(100L)
        println(Thread.currentThread().name + " Task 1")
    }

    launch {
        delay(100L)
        println(Thread.currentThread().name + " Task 2")
    }

    launch {
        delay(100L)
        println(Thread.currentThread().name + " Task 3")
    }

    println(Thread.currentThread().name + " Main thread is over")
    }
}
```